# Shell function that knows if it was called as a compound

Tags: bash, shell

How can you write a shell function that can find out if it was called from a compound command so that it can modify it's own behavior? It must do its magic thing only when called in isolation:

```
$ magic_function;
```

There should be no magic when it's part of a compound command, e.g.:

```bash
date; magic_function; uptime;

for i in LIST; do magic_function; done;

function funky () { do_this; magic_function; do_that; }
```

I've looked through the BASH manpage and exhausted my ideas around `$BASH_COMMAND` and `$READLINE_LINE`.

For some context, the function manipulates the shell history with `history -s`.  It should not do that if it was called as part of a compound.  I can find out if it was called from a function by inspecting `$FUNCNAME`.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to detect and why? Why does your function care how it is called? What an unusual requirement. It smells like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I stated the problem precisely.  Closing it and calling it an XY problem was very rude IMO.  The function is a command line utility function that does some history manipulation if you must know.  It should not do that if it was called as part of a compound command.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: Knowing that you are manipulating shell history helps us understand where you're coming from. You've been here a while so you've probably seen the types of shell questions the site gets. For every unusual-but-reasonable question there are 20 other impossible or misguided requests. People want to embed complex code in variables, parse JSON with awk/sed, or write scripts that generate code and call `eval`. When questions have questionable premises it's best that we nudge people towards better direction.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  I was actually agonizing over the original post text to try and avoid this exact scenario of being dismissed.

Comment: Hmm. There's a lot of magic one can do with DEBUG traps. Since the intent is history manipulation, though, I assume this needs to work in interactive shells? (If it were only for script execution one could check whether `BASH_LINENO` has changed between trap invocations).

Comment: ...btw, that kind of thing -- deciding which solutions are possibly workable in the larger context of the goal being served -- is part of why it's so important that we have enough of an idea around your larger goal to be able to discard approaches that wouldn't be workable, even if they could fulfill the narrow letter of the stated goal under a restricted set of circumstances.

Comment: (similarly, if the literal request is strictly impossible, it's often feasible to come up with an adequate workaround that serves the larger goal, _if we know what that goal is and why one has it_).

Comment: The problem with the `DEBUG` trap is that it only sets `BASH_COMMAND` to the current command.  It ignores compounds.

Comment: With regard to the literal request, I want to do this The Right Way[TM].  Not resort to barbarism.  Ergo the phraseology of my OP.